# Module will import another module indirectly but not directly

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I'm having problems understanding the way `import`, absolute and relative, works in Python.

I'll reproduce my working directory and omit some files for brevity:

```
A/
  B/
  __init__.py
  main.py
  C/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

`main.py` needs `f1` and `f2` from `module1.py`. `module1.py` needs `f3` from `module2.py`.

After tinkering and reading documentation I got to import functions to my `main.py` file from my `module1.py` file. I had to do the following inside `main.py`:

`from .C.module1 import f1, f2`.

`module1.py` depends on functions from `module2.py`. That is trivial: inside `module1.py`:

`from module2 import f3`.

This way I can call `module1.py` directly and it will load `f3`; however, in my main.py (which is a Flask app, by the way), it won't load, because `module1.py` throws `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'`. I think that has to do with the fact that I'm in a different directory now. Anyways, if in `module1.py` I change `from module2 import f3` to `from .module2 import f3`, `main.py` will work, but then I can't call the `module1.py` file directly because it will throw an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.module2'; '__main__' is not a package` exception.

**EDIT**: accidentally swapped names.

Notice that I have `__init__.py` in both directories/packages. What should I do so that both `main.py` and `module1.py` work?

Answer (score 1):

```
test
├── C
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
└── main.py
```

### `test/main.py`

```py
from C import f1, f2, call_f3

print(f1())
print(f2())
print(call_f3())
```

### `test/C/module1.py`

```
from .module2 import f3

def f1():
    return "f1()"

def call_f3():
    return "called " + f3()
```

### `test/C/module2.py`

```py
def f2():
    return "f2()"


def f3():
    return "f3()"
```

### `test/C/__init__.py`

This is what allows us to do `from C import f1, f2, call_f3` in `main.py`.

```py
from .module1 import f1, call_f3
from .module2 import f2
```

### Output of `main.py`

```
f1()
f2()
called f3()
```

Comment: This is basically my setup (`__init__.py` from `C/` is blank). In the way you've set up, if I do `python module1.py` I will get an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.module2'; '__main__' is not a package` exception.

Comment: Because you are relatively importing `module2` from `module1`. Check out this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/1305461) for more info.

Comment: What you have to keep in mind, is Python uses the import directories (`import .module` vs `import ..module` vs `import module`) relative to the directory you call `python file.py` from -- this is the easiest way to remember how relative/absolute imports work in Python.

Comment: This is way more complicated than it should be. I don't really know if I understood, but the answer you linked made it work. I'll read more.